# Are video streams(e.g. MJPEG streams) always connection Oriented?

Tags: video, stream, protocols

Is there any stream that relies on Connectionless protocols like UDP?

Answer (score 0):

That's like asking, "Are there any mad scientists that wear green lab coats instead of white ones?"

How would you find out? You would have to start polling mad scientists until you found one who says, "I wear a green one."

I doubt that any programmer alive is aware of every single video streaming protocol ever written. And if there were, they might be unware of one created tomorrow.

What would be a more interesting question is why do you think you need to know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: NO.

Reason: I am sure there is ONE video stream SOMEWHERE in SOME prootocol that is not connectionless.